# Cloud Firestore database structure for social media

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a simple Cloud Firestore database structure for a simple social media concept.

Each user can have at most one post (with the exception of a "most liked" post) that can be updated at any time. A user's "most liked" version of their post gets saved as a separate post which can get updated any time the user received more likes on their current version of their post than their most liked version.

I came up with a structure but I am pretty inexperienced with NoSQL database. Does this structure look like it will support my system? Also are these any glaring problems that will prevent important queries?

```
USERS (collection)
    DocumentID - userId gathered from Authentication uid
        firstName: String
        lastName:  String
        username:  String
        birthdate: Timestamp
        accountCreationDate: Timestamp
        post: postId (when user is created, create a default post document for them since there is only one post per user)
        bestPost:    postId
        FRIENDS (subcollection)
            DocumentID - userId of the friend
                username:  String

POSTS (collection)
    DocumentID - postId randomly generated
        authorUserId:   String
        authorUsername: String
        text:  String   
        imagePath: String
        location:  String
        likesCount: Number
        LIKES (subcollection)
            DocumentID - userID of the liker
                username:  String
```

The friends subcollection stores the friends username so creating a list of that user's friends by username is easy. I'm assuming I could then get more information of that user's friends by matching the documentID of a friend to the documentID in users.

Similarly for likes subcollection

Answer (score 2):

The structure looks okay.  I would offer a few comments with regards to doing this in Cloud Firestore.

**Updating likedCount**

If the post likes are likely to be infrequent (less than one per second), you can create a Cloud Function (triggered by a `likes` sub-collection `.onCreate`) which updates the `likesCount` using a transaction.  Make sure that the user cannot edit `likesCount`, within your rules.

**Allowing the user to edit the most liked post**

You'll need to build rules to enforce this.  This could be a little more complex and may require some strategic thinking (unless you already have a solution).

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention, the user should not be able to edit the most liked post but just view it. I'm a bit unfamiliar with rules so I'm going to have to research that a bit more. Otherwise the structure looks fine for this use case?

Comment: It may be easier to create a rule if you prevent the user from editing documents with more than n likes or if they haven't updated the document for more than n seconds.  There are no rules which will take the maximum number from a list.  Your idea means that any post which was only viewable before, will be editable once another post passes its like value.

Comment: @JasonBerryman Your answer states: "If the post likes are likely to be infrequent (less than one per second),..." May I ask what the reason for this is?